# How to add an array of objects into meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to add an object {taskId:'111', task:'learn meteor'} into an array of other tasks stored within a meteor document/field called myTasks.

I can add an array using $push but can't add the full object into each array item, just [111] not [ {taskId:'111', task:'learn meteor'}], [ {taskId:'222', task:'learn more meteor'}].

I could setup a new collection but wondered how I would add an array of objects?

Comment: Also I could store it a a string but then have to parse it after, which doesn't seem the right way.

Comment: What code do you use to do the $push you described?

Comment: Customerlist.update({_id:id},{$set { task : [ {taskid:'123', task:'work'}] }})

Answer (score 0):

Try `Customerlist.update({_id: id}, {$push: {myTasks: {taskId:'111', task:'learn meteor'}}})`. Refer to the mongo docs on `update` for mroe information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

Quotes.insert({
  name: 'Kate Monster',
  ssn: '123-456-7890',
  addresses : ['123','456','fff']
  })

Comment: And to add an array of objects just add objects inside the areay eg [ {name:'frank', age:'33'}, {name:'dan',age:'44'}]